# Difference between architectural styles and architectural patterns

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, styles, difference

what is the difference between architectural styles and patterns in software architecture?

Are they considered the same?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Architecture Style**

1. It is broader perspective in terms of defining a centralized layered concept for a system

**Architecture Patterns**

2. It is a coarse-grained solution to given architectural case study to follow certain principles, guidelines to build a robust system.

**To answer to your Question**

3. Both denotes the **same meaning** and please find this [link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/02/Architectural-Styles-Patterns) supporting to this [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ee658117.aspx).